# Order approximation for rational polynomial

Tags: polynomials, fractions, approximation-theory

I have this fraction:
$\frac{(-12a^3)d^3 + (4wa^3 - 16a^2)d^2 + (5wa^2 - 8a)d - a^2w^2 + 2aw - 1}{(- 12wa^4 + 12a^3)d^3 + (4a^4w^2 - 20a^3w + 16a^2)d^2 + (4a^3w^2 - 11a^2w + 7a)d + a^2w^2 - 2aw + 1}$

How can I approximate it so it may be written as a function of increasing order of d? As in $f(d)+f(d^2)+H.O.T$

I have tried using Taylor series but that is centered around a point (which I don't want). I am looking into Pade approximation but am utterly confused. Can someone help me?

Comment: [Long division](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_long_division) ?

Comment: @vadim123 Yes,I amtrying that...but I get stuck beyond a certain point. E.g I take a quotient of $\frac{((4a^3w^2 - 6a^2w - a)d)}{(+ a^2w^2 - 2aw + 1)}$  so it removes the d term from the remainder and so on....Is that right way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem is $$\frac{n_1d^3+n_2d^2+n_3d+n_4}{n_5d^3+n_6d^2+n_7d+n_8}$$
for complicated values of the constants $n_1,\ldots, n_8$.

Big O notation is useful in two contexts here; either for $d\to 0$ or  for $d\to \infty$.

If you expand as $d\to 0$, you get $$\frac{n_4}{n_8}+d\frac{n_3n_8-n_7n_4}{n_8^2}+O(d^2)$$

If you expand as $d\to\infty$, you get $$\frac{n_1}{n_5}+\frac{1}{d}\frac{n_2n_5-n_6n_1}{n_5^2}+O\left(\frac{1}{d^2}\right)$$

You can calculate these easily (and more terms if desired) on [alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/).

Comment: Thank you so much @vadim123 . Am I correct in assuming that if we want to include the $d^2$ term in the d->0 case then:

$\frac{d^2(n_2n_7-n_3n_6)}{{n_7}^2}$?

Comment: No, that is not the next term; see [alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%28n1*d%5E3%2Bn2*d%5E2%2Bn3*d%2Bn4%29%2F%28n5*d%5E3%2Bn6*d%5E2%2Bn7*d%2Bn8%29).

Comment: Thank you, @vadim123 !! I just did it for my problem and it matches with my (layman long division) method. At least I know I was going in the right direction. Thank you so much!